# Fill geom_tile with a gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient

I'd like to create a gradient plot. I thought filling my `geom_tile` with a gradient. However, `R` constantly tells me that `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`.

```
df <- data.frame(value=c(55, 40, 5),
             zz=c("A", "B", "C"))

df$lower <- df$value-2.9
df$upper <- df$value+2.9
ggplot(df, aes(x=zz, y=value, fill=zz))+
   geom_tile(aes(x=zz, y=value, fill=zz), width=0.2,height=2.9)
```

[image]

Now, I'd like to color the tiles with a gradient (most densely colored at the center (column=value) and fading out to the ends (upper & lower).

How can I achieve that? Is `geom_tile` the correct `geom` for this?
Thanks

**Edit**

The gradient should be within the tile, see this example from Alex Krusz. Link: [here](https://www.velir.com/blog/2013/07/11/visualizing-data-uncertainty-experiment-d3js)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think ggplot was intended for such use, but here's one way to simulate a transparency gradient.

Create dataset of interpolated transparency values:

```
library(data.table)

df <- setDT(df)
n <- 100
df.lower <- df[, .(ymin = seq(lower, value, length.out = n + 1)[1:n],
                   ymax = seq(lower, value, length.out = n + 1)[2:(n+1)],
                   alpha = seq(0, 1, length.out = n)), by = .(zz)]
df.upper <- df[, .(ymin = seq(value, upper, length.out = n + 1)[1:n],
                   ymax = seq(value, upper, length.out = n + 1)[2:(n+1)],
                   alpha = seq(1, 0, length.out = n)), by = .(zz)]
df.new <- rbind(df.lower, df.upper)
df.new$x <- as.integer(df.new$zz)
df.new$xmin <- df.new$x - 0.2
df.new$xmax <- df.new$x + 0.2

> df.new
     zz   ymin   ymax      alpha x xmin xmax
  1:  A 52.100 52.129 0.00000000 1  0.8  1.2
  2:  A 52.129 52.158 0.01010101 1  0.8  1.2
  3:  A 52.158 52.187 0.02020202 1  0.8  1.2
  4:  A 52.187 52.216 0.03030303 1  0.8  1.2
  5:  A 52.216 52.245 0.04040404 1  0.8  1.2
 ---                                        
596:  C  7.755  7.784 0.04040404 3  2.8  3.2
597:  C  7.784  7.813 0.03030303 3  2.8  3.2
598:  C  7.813  7.842 0.02020202 3  2.8  3.2
599:  C  7.842  7.871 0.01010101 3  2.8  3.2
600:  C  7.871  7.900 0.00000000 3  2.8  3.2
```

Plot the result:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = df.new,
            aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, 
                ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, 
                alpha = alpha, fill = zz)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = as.integer(df$zz),
                     labels = df$zz) +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Honestly, I've spent so many hours in this question and couldn't come up anything solid with geom_rect for gradient, but your answer is amazing playing with transparency!